# Does TSH and Growth hormone have any role in menstruation?

Tags: endocrinology, menstrual-cycle

Actually, I came across this on a mcq (multiple choice question) exam:

Name the hormone which has **no** role in menstruation:

**A.** LH

**B.** FSH

**C.** GH

**D.** TSH

(only 1 correct option)

Both FSH and LH have direct roles in the menstrual cycle, they're responsible for the follicular phase and ovulation, respectively. Menstruation takes place due to the decreased levels of progesterone. Does GH and TSH have any role in the process? If so what is that role?

Comment: I don't think they have a direct role but can affect menstruation indirectly by influencing metabolism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSH has an effect slightly similar to that of FSH and LH. This is found to be problematic in thyroid diorders. For example, in hypothyroidism the TSH overflow causes children to become fertile at an earlier stage, compared to the norm [1].

[1] Ann N Y Acad Sci. 1997 Jun 17;816:280-4. PMID: 9238278. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9238278

Comment: If hypothyroidism or hyperthyroidism resulted in menstrual disorders, then can't we say that thyroxine(secreted by thyroid) has a role in the proper functioning of the menstrual cycle, rather than TSH?

Comment: Not necessarily, correlation doesn't equal causation. While Thyroxine is the main hormone secreted by the thyroid, it doesn't directly mimic FSH and LH like TSH.